# Bash scripting: update a properties file

Tags: bash, properties-file

```
propertyOne=1
propertyTwo=a/b
propertyThree=three
```

How do I change the content of the property file to the following pattern?

- propertyOne will add a string before the original value
- propertyTwo will add a string in the middle
- propertyThree will add a string at the end

  ```
  propertyOne=apple/1
  propertyTwo=a/and/b
  propertyThree=three/end
  ```

I tried using `sed -i -e` but I am only successful if I hard-code the changes for every line; any suggestions for improving the code?

```
sed -i -e '/propertyTwo=/ s=.*/=one/2/two' path/to/file
```

Comment: property one will add a string before the current variable, property two will add something in between and variable three will add something at the end. They will be separated by slash "/". I will update the question for clarity

Comment: If all 3 replacements are different then you will need 3 substitutions and you cannot avoid hard-codng the property names.

Comment: this is noted, any idea on how to get the value of property one to reduce the error in hard coding?

Comment: Awk would be a better tool for this task. You might be able to do it in sed, but it will be harder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, a **pure Bash solution** offers both flexibility and robustness (but see further below for a faster `awk` solution).

While Bash solutions that read files line by line are generally slow, this probably won't be a concern with properties files, which tend to be small.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS='=' read -r prop val; do
  case $prop in
    propertyOne)
      val="apple/$val"
      ;;
    propertyTwo)
      val="${val/\///and/}"
      ;;
    propertyThree)
      val="$val/end"
      ;;
  esac
  printf '%s\n' "$prop=$val"
done < file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

The Bash builtin `read` conveniently offers rest-of-the-line logic:
by only specifying *2* variables in `IFS='-' read -r prop value`, the 2nd variable `value` receives *everything after the first `=`*, whatever it is, even if it contains additional `=` instances.

`< file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file` is a common idiom for (loosely speaking) in-place updating of a file. Technically, the modified content is written to a temp. file, and that temp. file then replaces the original.

<sup>Note:

* This indirect way of updating is needed, because the shell doesn't support reading from and outputting to the same file in the same command.

* This simple approach can be problematic, in that if the input file was a symlink, it is replaced with a regular file, the new file's permissions may be different, ...</sup>

---

**`awk`**, as demonstrated in [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40457383/45375), is certainly the faster choice, but it comes with a caveat - which may or may not be a problem for you:

Conceptually, a properties file is not strictly *field*-based, because a property value may contain *value-internal* `=` instances.

If you split the input into fields by `=`, then generic value handling can be problematic, because you won't have a *single* variable referring to the value *as a whole*.

<sup>A quick example: Say you have an input line `foo=bar=baz`, and you want to append string `@` to the existing value, `bar=baz`, without having to know ahead of time whether the existing value happens to have embedded `=` chars.

If you blindly use `$2 = $2 "@"` for appending, the resulting value will be just `bar@` - in other words: you've *lost data*.</sup>

Solving this problem requires a little more work; here's an `awk` solution adapted from karakfa's, which provides the *whole* value in single variable `val`:

```
awk -F= '
  # Capture the entire value (everything to the right of "=") in variable "val".
  { val= $0; sub("^[^=]+=", "", val) }
  $1 == "propertyOne"   { val = "apple/" val } 
  $1 == "propertyTwo"   { sub(/\//, "/and/", val) }   
  $1 == "propertyThree" { val = val "/end" }
  { print $1 "=" val }  
' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Note: If you use *GNU* `awk` and the version number is >= 4.1, you can use `-i inplace` instead of `> file.tmp && mv file.tmp file` to update the input file in-place (loosely speaking). Beside being more convenient than the latter approach, `-i inplace` also preserves the original file's permissions, but the basic approach is the same: the file is *replaced*, which bears the risk of replacing a symlink with a regular file.

---

**`sed`** is not a good choice, because it's hard to limit substitutions to part of a line in a generic manner.

Comment: thanks! but whats the purpose of the line > file.tmp && mv file.tmp

Comment: Led: Please see my update. I've also added an example to better illustrate why the accepted answer is problematic as a generic solution.

Answer (score 5):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[=/]' '/propertyOne/{$2="apple/"$2} 
                /propertyTwo/{$2=$2"/and/"$3} 
              /propertyThree/{$2=$2"/end"} 
                             {print $1 "=" $2}' file

propertyOne=apple/1
propertyTwo=a/and/b
propertyThree=three/end
```

define two field separators to be able to refer to components. Set up the new second field based on your rules and print.

**Note** Obviously, this approach is not going to work if you have `/` or `=` as part of your content.  You can generalize first and last rule to prepend or append to the value part of the equation but there is no way around the second case.

Also to have finer control on the rules you may want to change `/../` to `$1=="..."` for each case.

This is another alternative,

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS='=' '$1=="propertyOne"{$2="apple/"$2} 
                      $1=="propertyTwo"{sub(/\//,"/and/")}   
                    $1=="propertyThree"{$NF=$NF"/end"}1' file
```

testing with the edge cases

```
$ awk -F= ... << EOF
> propertyOne=a==b
> propertyTwo=a==b/c==d
> propertyThree=x/y==z
> Not_propertyOne=no change
> EOF
```

yields

```
propertyOne=apple/a==b
propertyTwo=a==b/and/c==d
propertyThree=x/y==z/end
Not_propertyOne=no change
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions above are good solutions. However, there's another more Java way to do this, which uses the same Properties class that Java itself uses, and could easily be adapted to edit XML-format properties as well.

Let's use the new Java 21 unnamed class feature and the new GraalVM native image feature to make a command that does exactly this for us. Create a file called `Setproperty.java`.

Note that there is no package declaration and no class declaration! The code shown below is the complete file.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if(args.length < 2) {
        out.println("Usage: setproperty filename propertyname [value]");
        return;
    }
    final Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
    if(args.length < 3) {
        out.println(p.get(args[1]));
        return;
    }
    p.setProperty(args[1], args[2]);
    p.store(new FileOutputStream(args[0]), "updated " + new Date());
}
```

Compile with:

```
javac --release 21 --enable-preview Setproperty.java
graalvm-jdk-21.0.1+12.1/bin/native-image --enable-preview -O1 Setproperty
rm Setproperty.class
```

You can now use setproperty in your script:

```
./setproperty foo.properties SomeKey SomeValue
```

It is as fast as any other compiled code - no JVM startup delay. This is a great use example for the new features of Java 21 and native-image.